# Azure AD Is it possible to hide or pass clientid and authority in body or header

Tags: azure-active-directory

I am using Azure AD authentication which is working fine but when the site got navigated to microsoftonline site **https://login.microsoftonline.com** the ClientId and TenantId are visible.

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
        new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
            // Sets the ClientId, authority, RedirectUri as obtained from web.config
            ClientId = clientId,
            Authority = authority,
            RedirectUri = redirectUri,
            // PostLogoutRedirectUri is the page that users will be redirected to after sign-out. In this case, it is using the home page
            PostLogoutRedirectUri = redirectUri,
            Scope = OpenIdConnectScope.OpenIdProfile,
            // ResponseType is set to request the code id_token - which contains basic information about the signed-in user
            ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.CodeIdToken,
            // OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications configures OWIN to send notification of failed authentications to OnAuthenticationFailed method
            Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
            {
                AuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailed
            }
        }
    );
    }
```

Is it possible to pass them in body or header. Also how to get the **AuthenticationProperties** which are stored and search for a property

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions("MyDomain")
```

I would like to read all the Options which are stroed and validate things

Answer (score 0):

Tenant id and client id will be visible in the URL.
Even if you could pass them in the headers or body, the user could still see them through developer tools.

Your tenant id is not a secret, and neither is the client id per the OAuth RFC (https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749#section-2.2):

> The client identifier is not a
> secret; it is exposed to the resource owner and MUST NOT be used
> alone for client authentication.

Comment: OK how to get the AuthenticationProperties which are assigned in startup.cs